# openUntitledDocumentOfType deprecated, but there is nothing better

Tags: objective-c

I have `document-based` application with function of converting first file type to second. To do this I create new document window with converted content. For me calling *`openUntitledDocumentOfType`* (and then sending there data) is the only work way. Unfortunately it's deprecated. Documentation of `ObjC` recommends to use *`openUntiledDocumentAndDisplay`* and change *`defaultType`* instead of those, but I need to have first type as default.

Do you know any better way to replace deprecated one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0k, I've found the best way to replace those deprecated message. Even there is no need to override `NSDocumentController`. I just create new document, load its `WindowController`, add it to existing `NSDocumentController` and then show it:

```
    NSDocument *document = [SecondDocument new];
    [document makeWindowControllers];
    [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] addDocument: document];
    [document showWindows];
```